# How to replace a keyboard input to specific text outside terminal input?

Tags: python, input, replace, keyboard, edit

For example when you type "abcd" anywhere on your device, it replaces it with "hello".

probably this https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html could help but im not sure

Comment: to do this you have to write your own terminal and register a signal handler for keyboard...Pygame, Qt, Tkinter or GTk can help

Comment: This will be device specific. Is this s smartphone, Windows or maybe just a single application? In any case, this is likely off topic for stackoverflow because there are likely multiple solutions and libraries.